# Parsing Atom Feed in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss, atom-feed

I've written the following PHP to parse RSS and Atom feeds.  This approach differs from others I've seen in that it simply checks a couple of places in the parsed XML for the item array.

```
function LoadItems($id, $feed)
{
    /* Load items into global $rssItems array */
    $rssItems = array();
    try {
        $rss = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<div>Load failed \"" . $feed . "\"</div>\n";
        return;
    }
    if (!($rss->channel->item))
        /* This appears to be where Atom feed item lists are parsed to */
        $items = $rss->item;
    else
        $items = $rss->channel->item;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item = array(
                "id" => $id,
                "feedTitle" => $rss->channel->title,
                "feedLink" => $rss->channel->link,
                "itemTitle" => $item->title,
                "itemPubDate" => $item->pubDate,
                "itemLink" => $item->link,
                "itemDesc" => RemoveLinks($item->description));
        array_push($rssItems, $item);
    }
    /*
     * Sort all items from all feeds in reverse chronological
     * order
     */
    usort($rssItems, 'RSS_CMP');

    return $rssItems;
}
```

My question is this.  I discovered this by accident.  I was just looking at the print_r output of the parsed XML files and noticed the different structures for RSS and Atom.  Is this kosher to do?  I mean, is simplexml_load_file going to put these items in this place for all atom feeds?  Is this solution then applicable to all feeds that are atom that are parsed with simplexml_load_file()?

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, RSS and Atom are 2 different standards. They both use XML but the differ in their structure.
`simplexml_load_file` in php is quite easy to use and you can check for specific parts of the feed (e.g. the `channel` in atom or rss starting with `feed`).

But if you want to do a little bit more with the feed data I would recommend you to use some libary supporting rss and atom so you don't need to mess around with the differences.

e.g. with [simplepi](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie) it's quite easy to access feed-data and it handels both standards (for help see [wiki](http://simplepie.org/wiki/))